# How much could a population of 100 million rise in 30 years?

Tags: humans, population

How high could a population of 100 million people rise in 30 years, living on a terraformed planet with more or less limitless resources and advanced life-prolonging nanotech?

Comment: I should perhaps note that there is some immigration from earth to Mars, but also vice-versa, so it more or less evens out.

Comment: What is their age distribution?

Comment: These are some questions which could severely limit the high-range of the number of  people, can you add them to your question? Are the resources limitless as in "you don't even have to worry about building houses", or there's some efforts needed to expand using these resources? Is your planet at peace during these 30 years? Has fertility improved with nanotech medecine? Are there laws which actively prevent or encourage big families? And yes, age distribution : You can't grow much if your population is mostly kids ^^.

Comment: The population could rise a lot, it could rise a little, it could decrease. For example, during the last few decades, the natural increase of the population of the USA, *"living on a* (perfectly) *terraformed planet with more or less limitless resources and advanced life-prolonging tech"*, varied between 8 per thousand per year in 1990 to a lowly 0.7 per thousand per year in 2020. (And voting to close because LibreOffice Calc is free, and Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel on the Web are free to use.)

Comment: The more prosperous and technically advanced the population, the lower the birth rate, traditionally. A high birth rate (rapidly advancing population) and technological proficiency are historically mutually exclusive. Also, the longer the lifespan, the lower the birth rate, historically.

Comment: Not much, if all the females are menopausal, or focused on their careers.   But if 75% of the population is randy and fecund 18 year old Mormon girls who think "Eight Is Enough" are shirking, and transmit that ideology to *their* children, then... LOTS.  It's honestly just math.  So that math in a spreadsheet with 100 people, and then multiply that by one million.

Comment: -1 for not using trivially available [world population data](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/population) to get your first order approximation. VTC:Opinion-Based unless you can explain with adequate detail exactly what "limitless resources and advanced life-prolonging nanotech" means.

Comment: Assuming the colony's population has access to comparable agriculture and medical tech as our modern time, the current global population of 83 million individuals per year would seem to suffice.  This might be reduced given the fact that there could be elder and juveniles in this population, as well as 100 million people on a single celestial body has significantly less population density (There are very few nations with 100 million people living in them.).

Comment: This question would be better stated if there was a specific population goal that was given, and the question would be the feasibility of achieving it. As stated, it is far too open-ended 'How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless societal mores and female psychology issues are addressed.

Answer (score 2):

## Up to 2-3 billion

Assuming they were really into child birth, and half were female, they could have one baby every 9 months on average, use advanced healing to recover, and repeat. That means 40 generations of 50 million babies, which is 2 billion. When their children were 18 some could join in.

That said, not all women are likely to want to constantly be pregnant, so less births are likely. 2-3 billion is the likely cap.

Comment: That seemed like a lot, so I did a bit 'o research. Women [can have 15-30 children](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-many-children-you-can-have-lifetime-2018-11) in their lifetimes assuming no magic recovery benefits. (I thought about telling my wife about this, then my sense of self preservation kicked in.) Assuming worst-case (all population is 16 years old, 90% women, and, um... "flexible" in terms of conception), that's 90M*30= 2.7B in the first generation. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ...However, I think a lifetime average number of 5 is closer to the truth and a female-to-male ratio closer to the world average of basically 50%, so 250M in 30 years with only one generation. Which is closer to the math Justin used 1950-1980.

Comment: They have advanced life preserving tech, so I assume they can mitigate or stop the effects of age.

Comment: Yeah... in that case your estimate could be considered very low.

Comment: My estimate assumes they're basically always pregnant, so it shouldn't be too low.

Comment: I noticed that! It was, in fact, the reason I started doing my research and found that link with its breathtaking estimate. However, one of the many reasons I voted to close this question is that I couldn't tell if a worst-case estimate was what the OP was looking for (probably not). Another was that the use of Clarkean Magic was undefined and therefore meaningless (at best, a convenient way to rationalize the worst case!).

Comment: @JBH
 15 children per female was not uncommon, one child per year or so for 15 to 25 years, starting at age 15 or so, except that it assumes the female survived every pregnancy, and all of the children survived. Even though menopause was around 45, few women lived to that age. The population NEEDED that high of a theoretical mother-to-child ratio to mitigate these two events, and when the world was at that that potential breeding ratio the human population barely advanced. So, eliminate death during pregnancy, and ensuring almost zero child mortality, humans have demonstrated the capacity.

Comment: Continued However, the females did not demonstrate the WILL. China no longer enforces the one-child policy, it is now the females who are voluntarily choosing it and the government  is discouraging them from doing so. China now needs MORE babies.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Please don't misunderstand me, my original comment found support for Nepe's post, which I felt was remarkable because my initial belief was that it was a nearly impossible number. While 15 children might have been "not uncommon" pre-my life, it's incredibly uncommon if not unbelievably rare today outside of 3rd world countries (and maybe even there). I've never met a woman who bore 15 children. I have known a family that had 12. One family in my 55+ year life.

Comment: @ 
JBH
 ????? I am in Mennonite country, so large families are the norm. Six to eight is considered a small family, and they are extremely happy with their choice. I find Nep's figures entirely reasonable, based on that experience, if not in fact a low estimate. I was pointing out that the proposed scenario is not only plausible, but is in fact common practice in some contemporary North American communities. The crux of the issue lies in the WILLINGNESS of the female to accept,  adopt, and live that lifestyle. It is definitely not a 'consumerism' lifestyle. Depends on the priorities.

Answer (score 2):

The highest population rates registred are around 3% to 4%.

These numbers came from natural growth, without migration.

So, 3.5% per year in 30 years increase the population in 180%. The 100 million turn in 280 million.

This scenario looks like countries in first to second step of demographic transition: high fertility rate while child mortality is in the ground.

To force women of the planet give birth in a high rate you will need some despotic ruler, and also make their workforce unecessary.

Btw, since your planet have tons of nanotech to prolong life perhaps they have some kind of artifitial womb and some Star Wars's Kamino clone factory technology, or the baby factories of Brave New World. This would make the growth rate skyrocket to any number of you desire.

Comment: They'd ask women if they wanted to have a lot of children, and pick their colonists out of those who said "Yes."

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the demographics of your people and their motivation.

One factor is age distribution. You want to know what percentage of you population is of child-bearing age. This tends to be 18 at the lower end for cultural reasons, and 40-45 at the upper end for biological reasons. The lower end is unlikely to change much, but the higher one might depending on precisely how this life-prolonging tech works. In a typical rich nation today this might be around 25-30% of the population, but with luck or good planning the proportion of your colonists might be close to 100% - at least until the children start being born, that is.

Gender distribution also matters. In most cases you'd have a somewhat equal distribution of me and women, but the number of working wombs is a bottleneck here. The higher the proportion of your population are women, the more growth you can have (up until you start having difficulty getting enough sperm samples to go around, but you'd have to get lower than 1% men before that is a big problem). It's unlikely you'd get that distribution on your first wave of colonists, but with the limitless resources having artificial insemination and selecting for gender shouldn't be a problem so I'll assume all future generations are 99% women.

I've run a short python simulation under these numbers to see what we'd end up with. I'm assuming one birth per woman per year, partly because you need recovery time and partly because it makes calculations easier. After 30 years you have 650 million adults and 4.761 billion children, for a total of almost five and a half billion people. Hope those limitless resources include robot nannies.

If you instead assume (perhaps more realistically) one child every two years, numbers drop to 350 million adults and 1415250000 children, for a total of 1.77 billion people.

All this is just a theoretical maximum, assuming your colonists had as their highest motivation to maximize their population to the detriment of all other pursuits. If you find a hundred million people willing to to that, and convince their children to do the same, you'd get these numbers. In any other scenario, the numbers will be lower - likely a lot lower.

Comment: "but the higher one might depending on precisely how this life-prolonging tech works."  Menopause happens when the eggs run out.

Comment: "I'm assuming one birth per woman per year, partly because you need recovery time".  Gah!!!! Children need to be nursed and cared for.  18 months is the **MINIMUM** practical frequency; 24 months is much better.

Answer (score 0):

In 1950, the population of Earth was some 2.5 billion people. 30 years later, in 1980, it was around 4.5 billion. A period of comparatively limitless resources (compared to the population and abundance of resources, there was no lack of resources during this period),  and it was during a period of exponentially decreased mortality and lengthening of the human life span.

Comment: So... given a starting number of 100M, (4.5/2.5)*100M = 180 million in 30 years assuming "limitless resources and advanced life-prolonging nanotech" has no relevant impact?

Comment: @ 
JBH I would posit this as a low ball park figure that has been proven to be doable. It was during this period that global food production was high enough to provide sufficient nutritious calories to the entire population, even though distribution was still a problem. Mineral resources, oil, and other energy resources were coming on line faster than the population could use them. All new manufacturing produced product that was in addition to current manufacturing. That is, new plants added to existing production, they did not replace it. So basically everything was in full expansion mode.

Comment: I should also mention that the graph starts at 1.8% per year in 1950, peaks at 2.09% in 1968, and then declines back to 1.31% in 2000. so the peak growth was in the middle of this 30 year range. The baby boom was NOT due to more females giving birth, it was due to more children and females surviving birth. Followed, of course, by the pill.

Comment: Those are great points! But I was gently reminding you that your post didn't actually answer the OP's question. No population estimate based on the OP's starting point. No percentage. It's just an observation of something that happened on Earth without much context.

Comment: @JBH
Truthfully, I am not sure what the OP question is, beyond "How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?" Does the OP want a reasonable answer, or something that is way out there? Conjecturally, one female could have multiple pregnancies, even ten or more at a time, with 'unlimited resources'.

Comment: We're in complete agreement about that.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent osteoporosis and have good enough recovery woman can give birth of 8 childrens every year - 6 month pregnacy and then early birth and child grow with nanotech help.

50 milion womans * 8 kids  = 400 milion kids every year.
And so on for 10 Years - 4 bilon kids.
Why 10 Years? After 10 Years with nanotech help kids will be grow enough to have kids.

- 11 year have 2.4 bilion births, total population 6.5 bilion
- 12 - 4 bilion, TP - 10.5B
- 13 - 5.6 bilion, TP - 16.1B
- 14 - 7.2 bilion, TP - 23.3B
- 15 - 8.8 bilion, TP - 32.1B
- 16 - 10.4 bilion, TP - 42.5B
- 17 - 12 bilion, TP - 54.5B
- 18 - 13.6 bilion, TP - 68.1B
- 19 - 15.2 bilion, TP - 83.3B
- 20 - 16.8 bilon, TP 100.1B
- 21 - 26 bilion, TP 126.1B
- 22 - 42 bilion, TP 168.1B
- 23 - 64.4 bilion, TP 232.5B
- 24 - 93.2 bilion, TP 325.7B
- 25 - 128.4 bilion, TP 454.1B
- 26 - 170 bilion, TP 624.1B
- 27 - 218 bilion, TP 842.1B
- 28 - 272.4 bilion, TP 1113.5B
- 29 - 333.2 bilion, TP 1446.7B
- 30 - 400.4 bilion births, total population 1.8467 trilion peoples.

This is theoretical maximum with extend use nanomachines and drugs, without use of incubators, artifical utreus, oviary extraction and modification.

Do not even ask about ethics.

Comment: 8 kids in one pregnacy/labor -  maximum obtainable by use drugs and nanomachines.

Comment: Fertility drugs? Multiple egg pregnancies? Why not a sex ratio of ten females to one male? Start with 90 million females. This assumes unlimited food availability. Four billion people is a LOT of food. And the female could not nurse that many children without supplementing the milk production. That is a lot of formula.

Comment: Resources are limitless. Including artifical milk and robot nurses :) Can start even with all females and sperm bank(limitless resource - sperm). Can remove male embryo too to get numbers doubled, 800m girls per year , 8 bilion in 10 years, around 4 trilions in 30 Years